# Nginx proxy: rewrite rule for root request

Tags: nginx

I have nginx installed on port 80 and a node application on port 2368 behind nginx

nginx configuration looks like this

```
server {
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    listen 80; 
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    } 
}
```

This configuration works exactly as expected. For example `/` request turns into `http://localhost:2368/`, and `/post/mypost` turns into `http://localhost:1234/post/mypost` etc.

What I want is that only `/` request turned into `http://localhost:2368/latestpost/`. And all other requests are handled the same way as in example above. Thnx!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `rewrite` directive:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    listen 80; 
    location / {
        rewrite ^/$ /latestpost/ break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    } 
}
```

or in separate location:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    location = / {
        rewrite ^.* /latestpost/;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering off;
    } 
}
```

Second variant is slightly more efficient as it will not try rewrite every request. But difference will be unnoticeable, I guess.